# Can not locate element inside the frame WHEN running all code

Tags: python, html, selenium

I want to locate the elements of a popup on some page,

the popup html is written in an iframe,

also the popup is triggered by clicking a link on the main page.

The weird thing is, if I run the whole code, I can not locate the 'target' element:

```
dr = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)

modify = (By.CLASS_NAME, "modify")
ec_visible(dr, modify).click()

popup = (By.CLASS_NAME, "add-addr-iframe")
dr.switch_to.frame(ec_visible(dr, popup))

target = (By.CLASS_NAME, "cndzk-entrance-division-header-click")
ec_visible(dr, target).click()

def ec_visible(driver, locator):
    return WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator))
```

But, if I first open the popup then locate, it works.

First:

```
modify = (By.CLASS_NAME, "modify")
ec_visible(dr, modify).click()

#popup = (By.CLASS_NAME, "add-addr-iframe")
#dr.switch_to.frame(ec_visible(dr, popup))

#target = (By.CLASS_NAME, "cndzk-entrance-division-header-click")
#ec_visible(dr, target).click()
```

Then: (works too if I manually open the popup and run this code)

```
#modify = (By.CLASS_NAME, "modify")
#ec_visible(dr, modify).click()

popup = (By.CLASS_NAME, "add-addr-iframe")
dr.switch_to.frame(ec_visible(dr, popup))

target = (By.CLASS_NAME, "cndzk-entrance-division-header-click")
ec_visible(dr, target).click()
```

Appreciate if you can point out my problem!

---

Here is the exception from shell:

> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

This is the html screenshot,
sometimes the content in iframe can not even be seen.

[iframe not extendable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnPZI.png)

[when iframe extendable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R93Zj.png)

---

7/26 update

I am wondering whether I asked the right question which may lead you guys just focusing on my code part. Since my code works(seperately), the elements and frames approach are good.

I step back and find one detail which may help but I don't know how it matters.

Here are the two shots about ctrl-F some element in the page source:

[Normal result: target found and highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOOAq.png)

[Weird result: target found and no highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqQzg.png)

I mean when the page exists 'weird result', my code does not work.

PS. The page is the order-confirmation part of an e-commerical site, but the site groups its goods into two types which led to TWO types order page.

Comment: you might want to use explicit wait in order to wait until the element you are interacting with is loaded on the iframe.

Comment: @PRERNAPAL I think my 'ec_visible' function is doing the job?

Comment: do you get timeout exception? Please paste the exception you are facing. I guess, your frame might be taking more than 5 seconds in being located.

Comment: @PRERNAPAL I added the exception, and changing wait-time to 30 seconds does not help, I guess it's not about it.

Comment: is it possible for you to paste the HTML here? after the pop-up appears.

Comment: @PRERNAPAL I added the related part as screenshot

Answer (score 0):

For ifarmes you have [`frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it) as the `EC`.

So try this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CLASS_NAME, "add-addr-iframe")))

target = (By.CLASS_NAME, "span.cndzk-entrance-division-header-click")
ec_visible(dr, target).click()
```

Comment: Tried and no luck, I think my 'ec_visible' does the same job in this situation since an iframe is also a type of element?

Comment: You need to make sure the iframe is available and then switch to it now the `visibility_of_element_located` returns the element while the iframe is not a regular element...

Comment: @spiderhami the return of `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it` is a `bool` not an element.

Comment: I did replace mine with yours and it returned True. Every part of the code is correct(elements are all available), but running them together will 'make' the target not availiable.

Comment: @spiderhami I edited the answer... see the change in the class_name `span.cndzk-entrance-division-header-click`

Comment: I added more description about my problem.(tried the span did not work either)